# how to print the content in android string XML file

Tags: java, android

i need way to read xml string file Because i am trying to make program read the strings and translate the content to another language to make another xml String file with new language

Comment: "I need _X_" is not a question.  Reading XML is a very common problem, and you should be able to get guidance from your favourite search engine.  If you have a specific question about actual code that is not working, please come back with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For accessing strings.xml through java use

```
getResources().getString(R.string.yourStringId)
```